# How to set up a TypoScript Playground in Typo 3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

How can one play around with TypoScript code shown in documentations about TypoScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with a local Typo3 test instance, Typo3 version 9.5.5, Official Introduction Package installed.

In the backend, create a new page in the tree. Rightclick -> *enable* it (the red overlay should disappear). Make sure it is selected in the tree.

Click on the blue *Template* button on the left. Usually it will show you the blue *No Template* message.

Make sure on the top *Info/Modify* is selected from the drop down.

Click the gray *+* (*New record*) button under the drop down.

On the bottom, click *Edit the whole template record*.

Optionally give it a speaking template and website title, like 'Playaround' and 'Play Around'.

Optionally, under tab *Options* -> *Clear*, select *Constants* and *Setup* - this will clear everything this Template [has inherited from parent templates](https://typo3worx.eu/2018/02/typoscript-explained/), but will also disable the debug infos at the bottom of the frontend for this page (if you have installed the Official Introduction Package).

Under the tab *General* -> text entry *Setup*, enter the following TypoScript:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = Hello World
```

press the *Save* and then the *View* button.

A new tab opens, showing you the frontend for your page, printing the text 'Hello World'.

Now you can play around with the code examples given in eg. the [TypoScript Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Introduction/Index.html).

Comment: I don't know if it fits, but if you need a local TYPO3 Installation to just play around with features, I can highly recommend [DDEV-Local](https://www.drud.com/get-started/).

Comment: @PeterKraume thanks for this tip. I did it with a XAMPP installation on Windows and then i have set up Typo3 manually. While this is not so simple it gave me interesting insights about the PHP.ini, httpd.conf and .htaccess configuration files and PATH variables like OPEN_SSL and how to get Graphics Magick running.

Comment: this is the manual configuration of a `root template`. easier: select the `Template` Module on the left side. select a page for your playground, if you have the view `Constant Editor` (default) or `Info/Modify` and have no current typoscript template you get the option `Create template for a new site`, which creates a root template for this page. with the selection of `Info/Modify` you can edit the setup with the typo3 editor which has some typoscript syntax support.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I just found out that Typoscript is by [definition](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/TypoScriptConfiguration/Index.html#:%7E:text=TYPO3%20uses%20%E2%80%9CTypoScript%E2%80%9D%20as%20a,specific%20needs%20of%20their%20customers.) not a programming language, but a configuration description. That's why Typo3 is needed as a substructure for this, I think. There seem to be online demos of Typo3 on the net, but I don't know whether they are up to date and whether you can test TypoScript there. Therefore access local containers / installations as suggested. Or if the possibility exists a dev subdomain.